# Setting up a git hook to add ticket number to git commit every time

Tags: regex, bash, shell, githooks

Hi there i want to set up a simple git commit hook so that i don't have to add the name of the Jira ticket to each commit manually.

Our Jira tickets all have names like:

**feature/DE-123-some-text-here**

I want to grab the ***DE-123*** bit and use it for my commits in the git commit hook so that my commit messages will look like:

`DE-123: Here is some code i've written`

I've worked out a simple regex to match this data:

`/(\w+-\d+)/`

but i can't figure out the bit of how to use it in my commit hook file. I have been messing about in a sh file to test it and i'm not getting anywhere.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks